# How to inject the Elasticsearch service to Kibana controller?

Tags: angularjs, elasticsearch, kibana

I am building a Kibana plugin which will query Elasticsearch on behalf of the user. The [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/5.3/development-elasticsearch.html) says that I could use the `es` service from the `kibana` module.

```
uiModules
.get('app/demo', ['kibana'])
.controller('demoController', function ($scope, esAdmin, es) {
  es.ping()
  .then(() => esAdmin.ping())
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('error pinging servers');
  });
});
```

However, the plugin fails to start with the following error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: esAdminProvider <- esAdmin <- demoController
```

It seems that the `es` service is not registered with the `kibana` module.

Then I tried to copy how [Console](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/5.2/console-kibana.html) works. It does not use the Elasticsearch service, but create a proxy API at the server instead. However, I have no idea how Console calls the proxy API with user's authentication information.

I am running out of ideas. Thank you in advance for any help regarding how to query Elasticsearch from the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Use esResponse, look at Tim roes kibana [plugin tutorial](https://www.timroes.de/2015/12/06/writing-kibana-4-plugins-visualizations-using-data/)

Comment: Thank you for the resource. Since I am neither building a visualization nor using the `TemplateVisType` service, there is no `esResponse` in my scope. In Tim's tutorial, it is all about handing over the data to `TemplateVisType` which query Elasticsearch for me automatically. What I want to do is to initiate a custom query however.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the elasticsearch module to the requirements for the module. Try:

```
uiModules
.get('app/demo', ['kibana', 'elasicsearch'])
.controller('demoController', function ($scope, esAdmin, es) {
  es.ping()
  .then(() => esAdmin.ping())
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('error pinging servers');
  });
});
```

Notable, this seems to work in visualizations and not hacks. The functionality of es and esAdmin seem to be limited. If you need to make elasticsearch calls they don't support, you have to make a custom server endpoint, and use elasticsearch from there.